# How to create an empty row below the current row inside an HTML5 table?

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to create an editable table where after filling a row an empty row  is rendered below the current row after hitting the tab button. Initially one empty row should appear when the table loads. Please some one help me to achieve my requirement.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Dynamic table</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js">        </script>
</head>
<body>
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>#</th>
                <th>user/site</th>
                <th>channel name</th>
                <th>actions</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td contentEditable="true">1</td>
                <td contentEditable="true">www.google.com</td>
                <td contentEditable="true">channel-1</td>
                <td contentEditable="true">delete</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td contentEditable="true">2</td>
                <td contentEditable="true">www.google.com</td>
                <td contentEditable="true">channel-1</td>
                <td contentEditable="true">delete</td>
            </tr>
            <!-- and so on -->
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where is your javascript code?

Comment: A simple Google search would yield you dozens of results. StackOverflow is meant to be a place where you can ask questions *after* you've searched.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can append a new row simply at the page-load by simply defining your javascript inside the `ready`-handler. 
To add a new row each time the `tab` is hit in the last `td` you have the listen the the `tab-key` (Keycode 9, see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode#Non-printable_keys_%28function_keys%29) for a full reference). As you add elements dynamically you have to work with [event-delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/).

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
    $('.table tbody').append('<tr><td contenteditable="true"></td><td contenteditable="true"></td><td contenteditable="true"></td><td contenteditable="true"></td></tr>');

    $('.table').on('keydown', 'td:last-child', function (e) {
        var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which;

        if (keyCode == 9) {
            $('tbody').append('<tr><td contenteditable="true"></td><td contenteditable="true"></td><td contenteditable="true"></td><td contenteditable="true"></td></tr>');
        }
    });
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Ldyfcg9p/1/)**

**Reference**

[.append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/)

[:last-child](https://api.jquery.com/last-child-selector/)

Answer (score 0):

use :last selector for finding the last tr in the tbody and then append the html like this

```
$('tbody >tr:last').after('<tr><td contenteditable="true">4</td><td contenteditable="true">a</td><td contenteditable="true">a</td><td contenteditable="true">a</td></tr>');
```